# Trying to send http request with json request body with \\

Tags: c#, json

I'm using C#.

I'm trying to send http request with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "Content":
    {
        "Id": 12345,
        "Fields" : 
        {
            "1111": 
            {
                "Value" : "FilePath;\\172.1.1.1\c$\test\test.exe,", 
                "FieldId" : 1111
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The request is failed because the `\\`.

How can i solve it?

I can to replace all the `\\` with another character but I have no the server side so I can't replace it again.

Comment: You could html encode / decode '\'

Comment: Create class, fill with data and serialize it. `var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourclassInstance);`

Comment: @Béranger JSON doesn't do HTML encoding, but the normal HTML encoding of ```\``` is just ```\```, so wouldn't have helped anyway.

Comment: Show the code you're using to encode the JSON data. We can't help you correct your code if you don't show the code to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would say the solution would be to do as Fabio suggested.  Create a class and use the NewtonSoft Json library to serialize your object into a Json string.

However, if you are looking for the quick and dirty solution you can escape the backslash with another backslash.  This will make it valid json.

```
{
    "Content": {
        "Id": 12345,
        "Fields": {
            "1111": {
                "Value": "FilePath;\\\\172.1.1.1\\c$\\test\\test.exe,",
                "FieldId": 1111
            }
        }
    }
}
```